# TFS API - Updating a work item field

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

Is it possible to update a field of a work item using the TFS API ?

Something along this line:

```
WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(Convert.ToInt32(current.WorkItemId)).State = rcbState.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: `WorkItem.State` is read/write so try it and see what happens. Just remember to call [WorkItem.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140425.aspx) when you're done with it.

Comment: Ahhh. I was missing the `WorkItem.Save` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set update your `WorkItem` properties as you show above, just be sure to save them once your done with it.

Something like:

```
WorkItem item = WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(Convert.ToInt32(current.WorkItemId));
item.State = rcbState.SelectedValue;
item.Save();
```