# is it possible to rollback iteration path change in online tfs?

Tags: tfs

instead of making manual change for every user story, is there a way to rollback iteration path changes online tfs?

I've tried changing it manually but it is time consuming, look for rollback option.

Answer (score 0):

VSTS/TFS doesn't offer a rollback feature on work items.

But you can realize a bulk edit on your work items 
[image: move to iteration]
or use the TFS API to know the previous state of your work items
([TFS 2013 API - Retrieve all changes made for WI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797660/tfs-2013-api-retrieve-all-changes-made-for-wi))
and reapply the modifications
([TFS API - Updating a work item field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639828/tfs-api-updating-a-work-item-field))